# return value of map operator[] (and "at" method)

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, stl

I have the following sample code to explain my question.  Per the STD map container doc (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/), the operator[] (or "at" method) returns reference to the mapped value.  I see why Line 13 compiles and works correctly (when I insert an element into vec1, the mapped value in map gets updated).  I don't understand why Line 13 does not cause a compile error since vec1 is not a reference and operator[] returns a reference.

```
  1 #include <map>
  2 #include <vector>
  3
  4 using namespace std;
  5
  6 int main()
  7 {
  8     map<int, vector<int> > port;
  9
 10     port[1] = vector<int>(1, 10);
 11
 12     vector<int> &vec1 = port[1];    // <===
 13     vector<int> vec2 = port[1];   // <===
 14
 15     return 0;
 16 }
```

I thought maybe the actual implementation of operator[] is overloaded to return both types (value and reference).  However, when I looked through the "map" header file, it did not seem to (unless I am missing something):

File : /usr/include/c++/4.7/profile/map.h

```
      // 23.3.1.2 element access:
      mapped_type&
      operator[](const key_type& __k)
      {
        __profcxx_map_to_unordered_map_find(this, size());
        return _Base::operator[](__k);
      }

#ifdef __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__
      mapped_type&
      operator[](key_type&& __k)
      {
        __profcxx_map_to_unordered_map_find(this, size());
        return _Base::operator[](std::move(__k));
      }
#endif
```

Can someone please help me understand this?

Comment: But `vec1` *is* a reference.

Comment: Sorry, I meant line 13, where vec2 is not a reference.  (I corrected my original question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Types are usually copy-constructable from a reference. So `vec2` is just a *copy* of the value referred to by the reference returned by `port[1]`. This is a simpler example involving `ints`:

```
int i = 42;
int j& = i; // j is a reference to i
int k = j;  // k is a copy of the int that j refers to, i.e. i.
```

Concerning your hypothesis about the two return types, you cannot overload a function by return value.

Comment: Thank you.  Your explanation and further reading up on "c++ copy-constructible" clarified what's happening and why.  (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_copy_constructible/    )

Comment: I accidentally ran into this issue, by forgetting to put the & when I declared vec type (as in Line 13), and took me a while to figure out the issue.  This seems like an easy mistake to make, with serious consequence.  Is there a way I can turn on some compiler options to give a warning for such occurence.

Comment: @AhmedA I doubt any compiler would issue warnings, because it is perfectly legitimate. It isn't usual to bind a reference to the return value. The typical use-case is to do something like `post[1].push_back(42)` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Line 12 initialises `vec1` to be a reference to `port[1]` (or, more accurately, the `vector<int>` object that `port[1]` refers to). So any change to `vec1` also changes `port[1]`.

Line 13 initialises `vec2` to be a *copy* of `port[1]`. So any change to `vec2` does not affect `port[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, so, I'll just try to explain to you what's going on in 12 and 13 lines.

```
vector<int> &vec1 = port[1];
```

Here you're creating a *reference* to a vector and initialize it with `port[1]`. So, in fact, they're pointing to the same memory location now.

```
vector<int> vec2 = port[1];
```

Here you're creating a *new vector* and copy all data from `port[1]` to it. They contains the same data, but they are not pointing to the same memory location.

So, if you'll do this:

```
vec1.push_back(1);
vec2.push_back(2);
```

You'll see, that `port[1]` now contains a new appended element - `1`.