# Acquiring a reference to unordered_map operator[] return value

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, rvalue

I would like to insert new elements in an `unordered_map` and update their value if they already exist, all in one step. I am doing this with the `operator[]` overload, which the docs say returns a reference to the map's value type.

```
unordered_map<int, size_t> map;
int &element = map[-3];
element++;
```

This does not compile. However, the following does, and executes as I expect (initializes the value to 1 and increments it if it exists):

```
unordered_map<int, size_t> map;
map[-3]++;
```

The following also compiles, but does not do what I expect (this is what I wrote originally, which resulted in a bug):

```
unordered_map<int, size_t> map;
auto element = map[-3];
element++;
```

The compiler seems to indicate that the rvalue `map[-3]` is an `int`, not an `int&`.

I took a look at this answer: [return value of map operator[] (and "at" method)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557857/return-value-of-map-operator-and-at-method)

But in that case the LHS type is enforced to be a value. How do I get a [mutable] reference back?

Comment: Try `auto& element = map[-3];`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is the value of your map? int or size_t ?

```
    unordered_map<int, size_t> map;
    size_t &element = map[-3]; // now it works
    element++;
```

`auto` discards reference while type deduction is done, you need to use `decltype(auto)` or `auto&` (what is more readable) if you want to modify value in map

```
   unordered_map<int, size_t> map;
   decltype(auto) element = map[-3];
   element++; // now it works
```

Comment: Surely you mean `value` instead of `key` ;)

Comment: Aha yes, the value is `size_t`! And thanks for the tip with `decltype`. Although @Sailesh D's comment above is probably cleaner?

Comment: Isn't `decltype(auto)` a bit of overkill? `auto&` or `auto&&` will work as well and much easier to understand

Comment: Not sure about etiquette but perhaps if you include `auto&` I could accept the answer (?)

Comment: @JVApen yep, thanks for suggest, i added auto& into answer too.